# According to EU compensation rules, can you refund one leg of the journey but reroute the other?

Tags: cancellations, compensation, refunds, ec261

In the case of the flight cancellation, [EC261](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Compensation_Regulation_261/2004#Cancellation) requires airlines to give passengers the choice of:

- re-routing
- later rerouting at the passenger's convenience
- a refund of the ticket

In case of cancellation of a return journey (aka. two flights, but booked on a single ticket),

1. Can a passenger choose a refund of only one of them (and the rerouting of the other)?
2. How is the price of the ticket (for the refund) calculated if so?

The price of the return ticket is not the sum of the prices of two single tickets for most of the airlines.